# Is address of global variable constexpr?

Tags: c++11, language-lawyer

Consider following

```
struct dummy{};

dummy d1;
dummy d2;

template<dummy* dum>
void foo()
{
    if (dum == &d1)
        ; // do something
    else if (dum == &d2)
        ; // do something else
}
```

Now, it is possible to call `foo` like this

```
foo<&d1>();
foo<&d2>();
```

and everything works as expected. But following does not

```
constexpr dummy* dum_ptr = &d1;
foo<dum_ptr>();
```

With this error from Visual studio

> error C2975: `dum_ptr`: invalid template argument for `foo`, expected compile-time constant expression

While this works

```
constexpr dummy& dum_ref = d1;
foo<&dum_ptr>();
```

In visual studio, but not in G++, because of

> note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   error: `& dum_ref` is not a valid template argument for `dummy*` because it is not the address of a variable
>
> ```
> foo<&dum_ref>();
> ```

EDIT:
Since C++17, `std::addressof` is being marked as constexpr, so I would guess it should work.

Comment: `foo<dum_ptr>();` does not work in g++ either.

Comment: Interesting. I tried it with `-std=c++1z` and it works, but you are right. It doesn't work with `-std=c++14`.

Comment: maybe `dummy const * dum` or `dummy constexpr * dum` in the template?

Comment: I am very surprised. How does it work with *position-independent code (PIC)*, Global Offset Table (GOT) and procedure linkage table (PLT)? Aren't these addresses sometimes may only be defined at runtime? What kind of magic is this constexpr address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC is right on this one.

The expressions are definitely [`constant-expression`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression)s*, since they are assigned to a `constexpr` variable. However, until c++14, there are additional restrictions on what is allowed for a pointer template argument.

> #### C++14 draft N4140 [temp.arg.nontype]
>
> 1 A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter shall be one of:
>
> - for a non-type template-parameter of integral or enumeration type, a converted constant expression (5.19) of the type of the
>     template-parameter; or
> - the name of a non-type template-parameter; or
> - a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of a complete object with static storage duration and external or internal
>     linkage or a function with external or internal linkage, including
>     function templates and function template-ids but excluding non-static
>     class members, **expressed (ignoring parentheses) as 
>     `&id-expression`, where the id-expression is the name of an object** or
>     function, except that the & may be omitted if the name refers to a
>     function or array and shall be omitted if the corresponding
>     template-parameter is a reference; or
> - a constant expression that evaluates to a null pointer value (4.10); or
>         a constant expression that evaluates to a null member pointer value (4.11); or
>         a pointer to member expressed as described in 5.3.1; or
>         a constant expression of type std::nullptr_t.

For `foo<dum_ptr>()`, `dum_ptr` isn't expressed as `&name`, and for `foo<&dum_ref>()`, `dum_ref` isn't the name of the object, it's the name of a reference to the object, so both are disallowed as template arguments.

These restrictions are lifted in c++17 to allow any constexpr, so thats why it works there:

> #### C++17 draft N4606 - 14.3.2  Template non-type arguments [temp.arg.nontype]
>
> 1 A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a
>   converted constant expression (5.20) of the type of the
>   template-parameter.  For a non-type template-parameter of reference or
>   pointer type, the value of the constant expression shall not refer to
>   (or for a pointer type, shall not be the address of):
>
> - (1.1) a subobject (1.8),
> - (1.2) a temporary object (12.2),
> - (1.3) a string literal (2.13.5),
> - (1.4) the result of a typeid expression (5.2.8), or
> - (1.5) a predefined __func__ variable (8.4.1).

As usual, clang gives the best error messages:
https://godbolt.org/g/j0Q2bV

---

*(see *Address constant expression* and *Reference constant expression*)